# Weavy chat - How to avoid asking "Third party cookies are required to use this page" every day on Safari?

Tags: weavy

I'm using Weavy (https://github.com/weavy, https://www.weavy.com/) v16.0.2 weavy-dropin.js.

Everything works fine in all browsers, EXCEPT in Safary: every day all users have to allow cookies, because it pops on the screen:

"Third party cookies are required to use this page [ALLOW]"

How to avoid it?

[image: Image Third party cookies are required to use this page]

On click in "Enable cookies":

[image: Cookie access]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Weavy's standard server will allow for the use of a custom domain, effectively transitioning the cookies from being third party

Comment: How to do it, @kris-ledel? But why does it work fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, this happens because the JS UI Kit is rendered in an iFrame with a different domain than the app it's integrated into.

To prevent this, you can use our React UI Kit or Web Components (coming soon!), disable cross-site tracking in the browser settings, or build your own custom UI. Additionally, when you self-host Weavy and ensure that Weavy is on the same domain as your website, there should be no problem with third-party cookies.